# Comparing two txt files and generate a new txt file with the strings that are only in one

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two txt files with a string per line. I want to compare txt file 1 with txt file 2 and generate a new file with all the strings that are in 2 but not in 1.

I tried something rather simple:

```
file1 = open("file1.txt", "r")
file2 = open("file2.txt", "r")

for word in file2:
    if word not in file1:
        print(word)
```

What this code does, it gives me all the strings from file2 if there is ANY string not in 1.

```
**file1:**
this
is
a
word

**file2:**
this
is
a
totally
different
word
```

What I would expect is only the string "totally" and "different". But I get all the strings from file2.

Comment: Try to use ```.readlines()``` on both the lines where you open the file

Comment: *"But I get all the strings from file2"* - That's not true. You only get "totally", "different" and "word".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[open()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) function returns file object, not string that is inside that file. In order to read text inside you'd need to read after you open file. Also it's a good habit to close files always when you open them. That's why personally I prefer to use command `with open('file1.txt', 'r') as file1:` to make sure that after I'm done with that file it's always closed and I don't have to run `close` method explicitly. It would look like this:

```
with open('file1.txt', 'r', encoding='utf8') as file1:
    with open('file2.txt', 'r', encoding='utf8') as file2:
        text1 = file1.read()
        text2 = file2.read()
        words1 = text1.split('\n')
        words2 = text2.split('\n')

        unique_words = list(filter(lambda w2: w2 not in words1, words2))

        for word in unique_words:
            print(word)
```

Comment: Probably issue is because of encoding. You could check the encoding of those files to make sure it's correct.

Comment: @KellyBundy you're right. My bad. Thanks. Fixed that in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `.readlines()` function which will convert all the lines in the text file to an element in a list or it will generate a list of the those lines.

```
file1 = open("file1.txt", "r")
file2 = open("file2.txt", "r")

f1=file1.readlines()
f2=file2.readlines()

for word in f2:
    if word not in f1:
        print(word)
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this:-

```
FILES = ['file1.txt', 'file2.txt']
SETS = []
for _file in FILES:
    with open(_file) as infile:
        _lines = [line.strip() for line in infile.readlines()]
        SETS.append(set(_lines))
print(SETS[1] - SETS[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with this solution:

```
file1 = open("file1.txt", "r")
file2 = open("file2.txt", "r")

word1 = [x for x in file1]
word2 = [x for x in file2]

words = [x.strip("\n") for x in word2 if x not in word1]
```

Output:

```
['totally', 'different']
```

I wrote `x.strip("\n")` because my example file contain a word for each row.